# Get price without currency symbol on one page

Tags: price

I want to load the price without the currency symbol on one single page.
I load the price currently with this code:

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php echo $_product->getPrice() ?>
```

should work if you have a product object in $product.

Comment: It works, but now it displays a price of $55.00 as 55.0000. How can I remove 2 numbers after the dot (.) So that it become 55.00?

Comment: Use substr($var, 0, -2); and remember to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I tried some code, but it did not work. What code should I completely use?

Comment: Remember this is not free consultation but a community site to help others. Code is really basic to any PHP user, <?php echo substr($_product->getPrice(), 0, -2) ?>

Comment: Sorry mbalparda, I keep that in mind! Thanks for your help

Comment: number_format($_product->getPrice(), '2', '.', ',')

Answer (score 1):

After get the `$_product` model, use the codes below to show price without currency, the second parameter `true` or `false` control the currency show or not.

```
Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice(), false, false)
```